# HideCaret() has no effect on Windows XP (x64)

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm trying to hide caret on my read-only EDIT control. On Windows 10 (x64) caret is hiding and everything works OK. But on Windows XP (x64) caret is still visible. What I did wrong?

```
BOOL OnCommand(HWND hWnd, INT ID, HWND hWndCtl, UINT codeNotify) {

  switch (ID) {
    case IDC_EDIT1:
      switch (codeNotify) {
        case EN_SETFOCUS:
          HideCaret(hWndCtl);
          break;
      }
      break;
  }

  return FALSE;
}

BOOL CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch(uMsg)
  {
    case WM_COMMAND: 
      return OnCommand(hWnd, (INT)LOWORD(wParam), (HWND)lParam, (UINT)HIWORD(wParam));
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: What is the return value of `HideCaret`? Are you sure that your control owns the caret when you call `HideCaret`?

Comment: Return value is: "1". I'm new in winapi, and don't understand what you mean "control owns the caret". When i clicking on EDIT it receives the focus but caret is visible on Windows XP.

Comment: The code you have looks correct, except for the fact that calls to `HideCaret` are cumulative (as per the documentation). That means you also need to handle the `EN_KILLFOCUS` message and call `ShowCaret`. There is no obvious reason why it wouldn't work on Windows XP. Are you sure that you're testing it in exactly the same way?

Comment: Also consider using the standard message cracker macros in `WindowsX.h` instead of writing them out manually. In this case, `HANDLE_WM_COMMAND`. Saves some typing, but more importantly, prevents errors.

Comment: Cody Gray, this is just sample code, and it doesn't work on Windows XP as expected.

Comment: Maybe something else is calling `ShowCaret` after your control gets focus on Windows XP. I faced a similar issue and ended up going "nuclear", and calling `HideCaret` in `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_CHILDACTIVATE`, `WM_PAINT` and `WM_KEYDOWN`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896767/hiding-caret-in-richedit-winapi

Comment: @TheNextman This works on Windows 10, but the caret is still visible on Windows XP 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Much easier.

1. Don't give the edit control the focus. You may remove the WS_TABSTOP style.
2. Don't use an Edit control at all and use a static control. This also has never a Caret.

Why do you use a Edit control and want to hide the caret.
Seams to be an X-Y question.

Comment: I think there are plenty of legitimate reasons for a "readonly" edit control (that actually *looks* readonly, i.e. doesn't display a caret). For example, readonly text that you would like the user to be able to select and copy.

Comment: But if you don't like the select and copy. You can use a static control for it!

Comment: @xMRi I need "select" and "copy" on it.

Comment: Even than. Use EM_SETSEL and WM_COPY. No need to do something with the Caret.